# Ruta con parámetro devuelve error 404

Tags: laravel

El primer ejemplo devuelve bien el texto. El segundo ejemplo devuelve página no encontrada al escribir en la url por ejemplo "*http...public/preguntas/animales*". ¿Qué sucede?

Primer ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/preguntas', function () {
    echo "Debe elegir un tema";
});
```

Segundo ejemplo:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{$tema}', function ($tema) {
    echo "pregunta sobre" .$tema;
});
```

¿Qué sucede?

Comment: Los parámetros en las rutas no llevan el símbolo de dólar, quitarlo debería solucionar el problema

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{tema}', function ($tema) {
    echo "pregunta sobre" .$tema;
});
```

Pequeño error en los parámetros de la ruta.

Saludos

Comment: ¿Y para que el contenido de esa variable $tema llegue al modelo "show" del controlador "PreguntaController@show" ¿Cómo lo pondrías? Gracias.

Comment: Haria lo siguiente: Route::get('/preguntas/{tema}','PreguntasController@show');  Y en el controlador:  public function show($tema){dump($tema)}

Comment: Gracias, eso he hecho al final. Muy amable Mr.Suk.

Answer (score 0):

Los parámetros en Laravel van sin el símbolo de dólar, por lo tanto tú ruta debe ser:

```
Route::get('/preguntas/{tema}', function ($tema) {
    echo "pregunta sobre" .$tema;
});
```

Comprueba en la doc de [Laravel](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/routing#required-parameters)